# Does Kiryuin Satsuki have any infused Life Fibers?

Tags: kill-la-kill

I know that Kiryuin Satsuki was experimented on by her parents to infuse Life Fibers into her.  She was too old at the time of the experiment for it to be successful but she was able to wear either Kamui (albeit to a lesser degree than her properly infused sister). I assumed when watching that she was partially infused but I now have no recollection as to whether that was clearly stated.  The wiki seems to clearly state that only her mother and sister have infused Life Fibers.

Does she have infused Life Fibers to any degree or is she 100% human?

Comment: Attached is the question which has another answer that made me doubt my interpretation. http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/31269/how-come-a-uniform-cant-be-made-of-40-to-90-life-fibers

Comment: There was some talk about non-infused people only being able to wear uniforms infused with life fibers up to x0%. I don't remember exact numbers, but it might be a key to Satsuki's own fiber content.

Answer (score 1):

She is 100% human, but she carried artificial finger nails made with Life Fiber (it is more likely to be a hidden weapon rather than an infusion with Life Fibers).

Kiryuin Satsuki waited until the last minute (until Ryuko arrived at Honnouji Academy with Senketsu) to wear Junketsu. And her butler was continuously against the idea of her wearing Junketsu. When after a fight, Satsuki always had physical and mental stress on her body and mind, so she always tries to end fights as quickly as possible when she is wearing Junketsu.

Comment: I'm not sure the nails (made from the same metal as her katana Bakuzan; not life fibers) nor the fatigue is all that relevant.  Neither of these show or hint whether she is 100% human.  The fatigue just shows she isn't like her mother or her sister.

Comment: She had years of training , preparing to wear  junkets on the other had her sister and her mother could wear them easily

Comment: I am not fully convinced.  There are several factors that contribute to that such as the mother's and sister kamui are cooperative. We already know that they are at least more infused than her.  It is unclear, however, if there is somewhere between 100% human and 100% infused.  She does take the same baths as her mother and drink teas infused somehow.  I will need to rewatch.  Sorry for being difficult to convince.

Comment: Well I'm saying she is human at least technically but I do agree she has some level of non human like abilitys but that can be also said about the students council members and they are also 100℅ human who are possession with some extraordinary abilitys .I think the same thing applies to satsuki too